# knockout form to django-rest-framework

Tags: django, knockout.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a knockoutjs form to my django site. Im new to knockout so followed an example but for some reason when I submit the page refreshes with no errors but nothing gets committed to the api.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<form data-bind="submit: mySubmit">
    <input data-bind="value: firstname" />
    <input data-bind="value: lastname" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        mySubmit : function(formElement) {
            var formData = {
                'firstname'              : $('#firstname').val(),
                'lastname'             : $('#lastname').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "127.0.0.1:8000/api/test",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                datatype: "json",
                processData:false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: I am now getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return firstname }" Message: firstname is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't declared observable's in viewModel . so consider declaring to make things go smooth .

**viewModel:**

```
var viewModel = {
    firstname:ko.observable(),lastname:ko.observable(),
        mySubmit : function(formElement) {
            var formData = {
                'firstname' : viewModel.firstname() ,
                'lastname'  : viewModel.lastname()
            };

            $.ajax({
               url: '/echo/json/', //mocking ajax request 
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result){
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
        }
    };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/rBTgT/7/)**